How can I have xref-find-references be verbose?
I have a weird problem.
When I start Emacs and run xref-find-references on a method in some C# code, it lists the references without problem.
Then, if I wait a few minutes and try the command again, it returns no references and says:

xref--not-found-error: No references found

Is there any way I can have it be more verbose about what's it trying to do?
The TAGS file is shown as the same, when I inspect the variable.
I can dissect my whole Emacs configuration, but I was kinda looking at some simpler way.
EDIT: I found now that I can M-x xref-etags-mode and then I'm allowed to use the command again, but it gives only results on some symbols, strangely enough and when it doesn't give a result, it pops up a new message
Buffer is read-only: #<buffer *lsp-log*>


How come lsp is still involved here?

You can instrument it and run it under a debugger and then step through it one function at a time (but you probably want to load the uncompiled xref.el file - that makes debugging a lot easier).

I see you're asking new questions on the site  Please, for this older one if you have further questions then ask them, otherwise accept the answer.

TL;DR: xref-* are a general API whose backends are replaced on the fly, which is why you see the behavior changing. If you want to make sure to always call specific backend function, you'd have to call it explicitly bypassing xref-*.
In more details:

The TAGS file is shown as the same
…
Buffer is read-only: #<buffer *lsp-log*>

How come lsp is still involved here?

This is because xref-* functions are a general interface to the functional of finding references, definitions, etc. When you start lsp, it substitutes the backend of finding references from the TAGS-related one to its own.
FWIW, this is the reason I never used xref-* functions when I worked with TAGS. Instead I called explicitly find-tag and other similar functions.
Regarding xref-find-references, it calls xref-backend-references which is said to have to be redefined by other modes. I haven't had success seeing what it's defined to e.g. in c-mode, see if you have a better luck with csharp-mode… But yeah, that part isn't well designed (it should've been a vector of backends to be "visited" by xref till the first one succeeding). You can also try using M-x profiler-start and then finding references, then invoking profiler-report to get the backtrace and hopefully see what function is being called by default.
